# Possible to map "exit" onto the X (close window) for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to get Chrome to save multiple windows, each w/multiple tabs when I close it.  This is possible by using Menu -> Exit but will not work if windows are closed individually using the "X".  Is there any way to change the behavior of the "X" to exit Chrome rather than closing just the one window?

Comment: I assume you're talking about on Windows… the answer would be 'no'. Closing the window deletes it from the 'reopen on launch' stack, as it is no longer open at Quit. Mac users would grok that immediately, but Windows users expect an app to Quit when they close the last window.

Comment: You should look into the Vivaldi browser. Vivaldi allows multiple profiles by a single button, and you do not need an account for each profile. They will succesfully close and reopen pressing that X button and it has many other great features, while still using the Chromium framework, so most of Chrome extensions work in Vivaldi.